# Need Help Downloading Albow Library

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am trying to download a library called Albow. I tried using pip to install it, but it didn't work, so I went to the [Albow website](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Albow/) and it linked to a .zip file. Basically what I want to do is to make it so that when I type:

```
import albow
```

Python recognizes it.

I'm using Python 3.5.3, on a Debian Linux VM. My PC's OS is using ChromeOS.

**If I missed something that I should explain, I will edit the question.**

Comment: Download the ZIP and unpack it then read the README file that is inside. It says: *"Contents: `albow` - Package containing the Python modules. Put it on your `PYTHONPATH` or **in the top level directory of your PyGame application**."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Albow website](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Albow/) you linked to (or this [other one](https://www.pygame.org/project/338/4687) from the Pygame projects) only supports Python 2. It's not available in PyPi so `pip install` would not work.

Since you tagged this [python3.5](/questions/tagged/python3.5), I assume you want Python 3 support.
There is a ported version available from PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/python3-albow/.

> This project is a port of Gregory Ewing's Albow project (https://www.pygame.org/project/338/4687) that is only compatible with Python 2 and is unsupported since 2014.

You should be able to install it using standard `pip install`

```
$ python3.5 -m pip install --user python3-albow
...
Installing collected packages: pygame, python3-albow
Successfully installed pygame-1.9.6 python3-albow-2.7.8

$ python3.5
Python 3.5.9 (default, Nov 24 2019, 01:35:13) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import albow
>>> albow.__path__
['/home/gino/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/albow']
>>>
```

Or, preferably, setup a virtual environment and install it there.